# Postgresql and inline functions

Tags: postgresql, inline

How can i declare non-inline function in postgresql? Only with adding 'out' argument? 

Is table functions(returns table) inline?

Comment: Post code of what you're trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inlining is always an optimization<sup>1</sup> - this means that "*the system*" will perform inlining *only* when it is *sure* that the result is just the same as without inlining.

So: If you ask "how can I prevent inlining" you should better ask "What I'm doing wrong or why behaves "*the system*" wrong?" and solve *that* problem.

<sup>1</sup> Whether a successfull optimizazion or not is not the question here.

Comment: Ok, can this function can be inlined?
create function Tabli()
returns table(Type character varying(15), Cost bigint) AS $$
begin
 return query select "Type", sum("Cost") from "tblProject"
 group by "Type";
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

Comment: Thank for your answer, i have read documentation one more time and understand inline oprimization.